# How to open excel files, which are located in a google drive folder with google script?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-apps

I need to open excel files in given google drive folder and read its data. For that, I used the following code.

```
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Test Folder");
  var foldersnext = folders.next();
  var files = foldersnext.getFiles(); // get all files from folder

  while(files.hasNext()) {

    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(files.next().getUrl());   // Line A     

  }
```

But it gives an error in "Line A" like this;

> Document 1LDVkBTnkcY32ni9WoGDn6xHonPOX87ZV is missing (perhaps it was
>   deleted, or you don't have read access?)

But when Log the IDs of the files using,

```
var selectedFile = files.next();
Logger.log(selectedFile.getId());
```

It gives me the expecting result. So, I think the error is in converting the file to excel file. Please give me a solution to **open multiple excel files in a given folder and read its data...**

This project has the following scopes

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve values from Excel file on your Google Drive.
- Excel files are put in a folder of "Test Folder".

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- In order to retrieve values from Excel file, at first, the Excel file is required to be converted to Google Spreadsheet. After converted it, the values can be retrieved by Spreadsheet Service.

  - It is considered that the reason of the error is due to that Excel file is tried to be opened by Spreadsheet Service.
- In this modified script, I used `Drive.Files.copy()` for converting from Excel file to Google Spreadsheet.

#### Before run the script:

When you run the script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services as follows. This modified script used Drive API of Advanced Google Services.

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Drive API v2

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
while(files.hasNext()) {

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(files.next().getUrl());   // Line A     

}
```

To:

```
while(files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {
    var resource = {
      title: file.getName(),
      parents: [{id: foldersnext.getId()}],
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
    };
    var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.copy(resource, file.getId());
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.id);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- If the Excel file is large, an error might occur.
- If the number of Excel files are large, an error might occur. In this case, please tell me.
- In this sample script, the converted Spreadsheet is created to the same folder of Excel file. If you want to delete the file after the values were retrieved, please use `Drive.Files.remove(fileId)`.

#### References:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy)
- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

From your comment, it was found that my understanding was correct. So as a test case, can you test the following flow?

1. Create new folder.
2. Put an Excel file in the created folder.

   - Please copy the folder ID. This folder ID is used at the script.
3. Please confirm whether Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google Services.
4. Run the following sample script. Before run it, please set the folder ID.

   ```
   function sample() {
     var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.

     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
     var files = folder.getFiles();
     while(files.hasNext()) {
       var file = files.next();
       if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {
         var resource = {
           title: file.getName(),
           parents: [{id: folderId}],
           mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
         };
         var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.copy(resource, file.getId());
         var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.id).getSheets()[0];
         var value = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
         Logger.log(value)
       }
     }
   }
   ```
5. Run the function of `sample()` at the script editor.
6. After the script is finished, please check the log.

   - If you can see the values of Excel file at the log, it is found that the script works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in this way it does not read any files either.

Comment: When I check the details of the file, it says their type is `Google sheets`.

Comment: @dilusha_dasanayaka Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. At first, I would like to confirm whether my understanding for your question is correct. You want to retrieve values from Excel file on your Google Drive. Excel files are put in a folder of "Test Folder". About them, is my understanding correct? And about ``When I check the details of the file, it says their type is Google sheets``, I couldn't understand about your situation. Can I ask you about the file of ``the details of the file``?

Comment: @dilusha_dasanayaka In my modified script, if Excel files are in the folder of ``Test Folder``, those Excel files are converted to Google Spreadsheet and you can retrieve values from the converted Google Spreadsheet. If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. And also, can you provide the detail flow and script for replicating your current issue? I would like to confirm about the issue from the provided information. If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: @dilusha_dasanayaka By the way, in the modified script, the scope of ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`` is required. If the error related to the scopes, please add it and run again.

Comment: @dilusha_dasanayaka Thank you for replying. But unfortunately, I couldn't think of the solution of your current issue from your reply. In order to think of your current issue, more information is required. Can you provide more information of your current issue? If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. If you cannot understand my answer and comments because of my poor English skill. Please tell me.

Comment: @dilusha_dasanayaka I apologize for the inconvenience. I added a sample script for testing. Could you please confirm it? In my environment, I could confirm that the script worked. But if the script didn't work in your environment, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, buddy. First I forgot to delete the newly created `spread sheet` which created by our script. hence it runs infinitely. Finally I fixed it. Thanks again for your help and kind follow up.

Comment: @dilusha_dasanayaka Thank you for testing and your support. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.