# Stop script from creating same file again or/and overwriting existing one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

EDIT
I edited the title to a better one.
From: Stop script from creating same file again
To: Stop script from creating same file again or/and overwriting existing one

---

With help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66695743/how-to-add-a-formula-to-all-spreadsheets-in-a-folder-using-a-script#comment117933455_66695743) by **Cooper** and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161027/15425623) by **Tanaike** I made a script like this.

**Problem**
When I run the code 1 time **AND RUN AGAIN** there is another file again.
How can I stop this? I do not want the script to create second file IF I already have it.

```
function excel2SheetsAndSorting4LED(){
  sta56160812();
  loadSortSheetsInFolder();
}

// this from Tanaike
function sta56160812() {
  // const folderId = "xxxxx"; // Please set the folder ID.
  var sourceFldrId = "xxxxx"; // ID of SOURCE folder
  var destinationFldrId = "zzzzz"; // ID of DESTINATION folder (can be the same folder)

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFldrId);
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {
      var name = file.getName().split('.')[0];
      var resource = {
        title: name + '_converted',
        parents: [{id: destinationFldrId}],
        mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
      };
      var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.copy(resource, file.getId());
      // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.id).getSheets()[0];
      // var value = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      // Logger.log(value)
    }
  }
}

// and this from Cooper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66695743/how-to-add-a-formula-to-all-spreadsheets-in-a-folder-using-a-script#comment117933455_66695743
function loadAndSortSpreadsheetsInFolder() {
    const values = [
        [1, 'where Col5<>0', "=COUNTA(K4:K)",'', "=COUNTA(M4:M)", "=COUNTA(N4:N)"],
        [2, "=IF(K2=FALSE,,\" and Col5<=95\")", '', '', '', ''],
        [3, "=QUERY(SORT({A3:B,C3:C+0,D3:D,E3:G+0,Y3:AF},3,0,5,1),J1&J2,1)", '', '', '', '']
    ];
    const destinationFldrId = "zzzzz"; // ID of DESTINATION folder (can be the same folder) //
    const fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFldrId);
    let files = fldr.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        let file = files.next();
        let id = file.getId();
        let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
        let sh = ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss);
        sh.setTabColor("ff0000");
        ss.moveActiveSheet(1);
        let rg1 = sh.getRange("I1:Y").clear();
        let rg2 = sh.getRange(1, 9, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
        let rg3 = sh.getRange(2,11).insertCheckboxes();
    }
}
```

And also the script is slow because it first create all files and then write on them.
How can I make it to create in destination, open file one time, write, close, go to next?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When you run the function of `sta56160812()`, when the same filename of the converted Spreadsheet is existing, you don't want to create new Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to include the function of `loadAndSortSpreadsheetsInFolder()` in the function of `sta56160812()`.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, from your script, I would like to propose to check the filename of `var name = file.getName().split('.')[0] + '_converted'` in the destination folder.
- From your question, I'm not sure about what you want to do when the same filename is existing in the destination folder. So in this answer, I would like to overwrite the existing file with `const file = files.next()`.
- In order to include the function of `loadAndSortSpreadsheetsInFolder()` in the function of `sta56160812()`, do while loop in `sta56160812()` is modified.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your `sta56160812()` as follows.

From:

```
while(files.hasNext()) {
  const file = files.next();
  if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {
    var name = file.getName().split('.')[0];
    var resource = {
      title: name + '_converted',
      parents: [{id: destinationFldrId}],
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
    };
    var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.copy(resource, file.getId());
    // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.id).getSheets()[0];
    // var value = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    // Logger.log(value)
  }
}
```

To:

```
while (files.hasNext()) {
  const file = files.next();
  if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {
    var name = file.getName().split('.')[0] + '_converted';
    var existingFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
    var spreadsheetId;
    if (existingFile.hasNext()) {
      var id = existingFile.next().getId();
      spreadsheetId = Drive.Files.update({}, id, file.getBlob()).id;
    } else {
      var resource = {
        title: name,
        parents: [{ id: destinationFldrId }],
        mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
      };
      spreadsheetId = Drive.Files.copy(resource, file.getId()).id;
    }

    // Below script is from loadAndSortSpreadsheetsInFolder().
    const values = [
      [1, 'where Col5<>0', "=COUNTA(K4:K)",'', "=COUNTA(M4:M)", "=COUNTA(N4:N)"],
      [2, "=IF(K2=FALSE,,\" and Col5<=95\")", '', '', '', ''],
      [3, "=QUERY(SORT({A3:B,C3:C+0,D3:D,E3:G+0,Y3:AF},3,0,5,1),J1&J2,1)", '', '', '', '']
    ];
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
    let sh = ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss);
    sh.setTabColor("ff0000");
    ss.moveActiveSheet(1);
    let rg1 = sh.getRange("I1:Y").clear();
    let rg2 = sh.getRange(1, 9, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    let rg3 = sh.getRange(2,11).insertCheckboxes();
  }
}
```

- And, in this modification, please remove `loadSortSheetsInFolder();` from `excel2SheetsAndSorting4LED()`.

#### Note:

- If you don't want to overwrite the existing file, please remove `var id = existingFile.next().getId();` and `spreadsheet = Drive.Files.update({}, id, file.getBlob());` from above modified script.
- This modified script supposes that in your environment, Drive API has already been enabled at Advanced Google services. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: update of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)

### Added 1:

From your following replying,

> I am very sorry for the confusion. My english also are not very good (I hope is better when I have more time to think). Stop the script from creating the same file again AND also NOT overwrite existing converted file with same name is the more detailed question. Like before script: Source folder= file01.xlsx, file02.xlsx. Destination folder= file01_converted, file03, file04. After script: Destination folder: file01_converted (old file), file02_converted (new file), file03, file04. I hope I make it clear now and sorry again for the confusion. Thank you @Tanaike

In above situation, I understood that  `(old file)` of `file01_converted (old file)` and  `(new file)` of `file02_converted (new file)` are not included in the filename. If my understanding is correct, in this case, I think that removing the script in the if statement when `existingFile.hasNext()` is suitable. The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your `sta56160812()` as follows.

From:

```
while(files.hasNext()) {
  const file = files.next();
  if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {
    var name = file.getName().split('.')[0];
    var resource = {
      title: name + '_converted',
      parents: [{id: destinationFldrId}],
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
    };
    var spreadsheet = Drive.Files.copy(resource, file.getId());
    // var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.id).getSheets()[0];
    // var value = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    // Logger.log(value)
  }
}
```

To:

```
while (files.hasNext()) {
  const file = files.next();
  if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || file.getMimeType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {
    var name = file.getName().split('.')[0] + '_converted';
    var existingFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
    if (!existingFile.hasNext()) {
      var resource = {
        title: name,
        parents: [{ id: destinationFldrId }],
        mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
      };
      var spreadsheetId = Drive.Files.copy(resource, file.getId()).id;

      // Below script is from loadAndSortSpreadsheetsInFolder().
      const values = [
          [1, 'where Col5<>0', "=COUNTA(K4:K)",'', "=COUNTA(M4:M)", "=COUNTA(N4:N)"],
          [2, "=IF(K2=FALSE,,\" and Col5<=95\")", '', '', '', ''],
          [3, "=QUERY(SORT({A3:B,C3:C+0,D3:D,E3:G+0,Y3:AF},3,0,5,1),J1&J2,1)", '', '', '', '']
      ];
      let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
      let sh = ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss);
      sh.setTabColor("ff0000");
      ss.moveActiveSheet(1);
      let rg1 = sh.getRange("I1:Y").clear();
      let rg2 = sh.getRange(1, 9, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
      let rg3 = sh.getRange(2,11).insertCheckboxes();
    }
  }
}
```

- In this case, when the same filename is existing in the destination folder, the script of `if (!existingFile.hasNext()) {}` is not run.

### Added 2:

From your following replying,

> Beautiful. Can you add the last thing from here? How can I move new tab ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss) from 2nd tab position to first?

#### Sample script:

The simple sample script for moving the new sheet created by `ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss)` to the 1st tab is as follows.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###"); // or .getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const newSheet = ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss);
  ss.setActiveSheet(newSheet);
  ss.moveActiveSheet(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tanaike. I will test and come back soon.

Comment: @Swen Thank you for replying. When I misunderstood your question, I apologize for this. At that time, please tell me. I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: Tanaike you understand almost correct and script works. Thank you. BUT. **I am not sure what is best**. Overwrite all files like script does now OR leave alone existing files? **Because if files are already in destination, maybe there are modifications in files I must keep**. How can I have this alternative to **skip existing files in destination**? And one last thing. How can I move new tab `ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss)` from 2nd tab position to first? I cannot find how anywhere I looked. Can you include this or I must start new post? Thank you again.

Comment: @Swen Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `BUT. I am not sure what is best.`, unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand what you want to do when the same filename is existing in the destination folder as mentioned in my answer. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. By this, as a sample, I included the script for overwriting. So you can remove the script. About this, I think that this depends on your actual goal. So can I ask you about what you want to do? From this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Swen About `Because if files are already in destination, maybe there are modifications in files I must keep.`, in this case, I think your current script can be used. But, in your question, you say `When I run the code 1 time AND RUN AGAIN there is another file again. How can I stop this?`. So I'm confusing your goal. I apologize for this. In this case, can I ask you about the detail of your goal? About your 3rd question of `How can I move new tab ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss) from 2nd tab position to first?`, this can be achieved. But, I think that how about resolving from your 1st question?

Comment: I am very sorry for the confusion. My english also are not very good (I hope is better when I have more time to think). **Stop the script from creating the same file again AND also NOT overwrite existing converted file with same name** is the more detailed question. Like **before script**: Source folder= `file01.xlsx`, `file02.xlsx`. Destination folder= `file01_converted`, `file03`, `file04`. **After script**: Destination folder: `file01_converted (old file)`, `file02_converted (new file)`, `file03`, `file04`. I hope I make it clear now and sorry again for the confusion. Thank you @Tanaike

Comment: @Swen Thank you for replying. From your replying, I added one more modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Thank you for immediate reply. I will test now.

Comment: Beautiful. Can you add the last thing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743586/stop-script-from-creating-same-file-again/66746415?noredirect=1#comment117998471_66746415)? `How can I move new tab ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss) from 2nd tab position to first?`

Comment: @Swen Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your 2nd question of `How can I move new tab ss.getSheets()[0].copyTo(ss) from 2nd tab position to first?`, I added a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? By the way, one question can have one question. So when you post your questions in the future, please be careful this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230245/discussion-between-swen-and-tanaike).